# Use generic enum classes in maps

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a map of class names to their enum class and I have method that parses a string like `"SomeEnum.FIRST"` into the actual object. But `Enum.valueOf` doesn't accept `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` while the map cannot store `Class<T extends Enum<T>>`.

For the code, the map looks something like this:

```
    private static final HashMap<String, Class<? extends Enum<?>>> enumsMap;

    static {
        enumsMap = new HashMap<>();
        // These are two DIFFERENT enum classes!
        registerEnum(SomeEnum.class);
        registerEnum(AnotherEnum.class);
    }

    private static void registerEnum(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass) {
        enumsMap.put(enumClass.getSimpleName(), enumClass);
    }
```

And here is the parser (removed unnecessary code):

```
    public <T extends Enum<T>> Object[] parse(List<String> strParameters) {
        Object[] parameters = new Object[strParameters.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
            String strParameter = strParameters.get(i);
            int delim = strParameter.lastIndexOf('.');
            String className = strParameter.substring(0, delim - 1);
            String enumName = strParameter.substring(delim + 1);
            Class<T> enumClass = (Class<T>) enumsMap.get(className);
            parameters[i] = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, enumName);
        }
        return parameters;
    }
```

And now if I call this `parse`, my IDE (Android Studio) tells me, that "Unchecked method 'parse(List)' invocation", and afaik this is because of that generic type. If I remove it in `parse`, it wouldn't compile but the warning disappears. Is there a good way around it?

Comment: It is unchecked because compiler cannot ensure that `strParameters` only contains entries for the given `T`. Besides, if the caller knows the enum, i.e. `T` (otherwise you can't call it anyway), why would you need to lookup in the map? Re-think what you're doing. Probability is that you should simply remove `T`

Comment: @Andreas if I remove `T` in `parse`, `Enum.valueOf` complains that the class is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have enums like:

```java
  enum Foo {
    A, B, C
  }

  enum Bar {
    D, E, F
  }
```

Then you can implement the kind of map you're talking about with the following code.

```java
class MyEnums {
    private final Map<String, Class<? extends Enum<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void addEnum(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
      map.put(e.getSimpleName(), e);
    }

    private <T extends Enum<T>> T parseUnsafely(String name) {
      final int split = name.lastIndexOf(".");
      final String enumName = name.substring(0, split);
      final String memberName = name.substring(split + 1);
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Class<T> enumType = (Class<T>) map.get(enumName);
      return Enum.valueOf(enumType, memberName);
    }

    public Object parse(String name) {
      return parseUnsafely(name);
    }

    public Object[] parseAll(String... names) {
      return Stream.of(names)
          .map(this::parse)
          .collect(toList())
          .toArray();
    }
  }
```

This does *not* get around an unchecked cast, though; it only hides it from you temporarily.  You can see where  where `SuppressWarnings` is used to muffle the warning about `enumType`.  It's generally good practice to apply the warning suppression in as limited a scope as possible.  In this case, it's for that single assignment.  While this could be a red flag in general, in the present case we know that the only values in the map are, in fact, enum classes, since they must have been added by `addEnum`.

Then, it can be used as:

```
  MyEnums me = new MyEnums();
  me.addEnum(Foo.class);
  me.addEnum(Bar.class);
  System.out.println(me.parse("Foo.A"));
  System.out.println(me.parse("Bar.E"));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(me.parseAll("Foo.B", "Bar.D", "Foo.C")));
```

which prints:

```
A
E
[B, D, C]
```

You'll notice that I broke `parseUnsafely` and `parse` into separate methods.  The reason that we don't want to expose `parseUnsafely` directly is that it makes a guarantee by its return type that we cannot actually enforce.  If it were exposed, then we could write code like

```
Bar bar = me.parseUnsafely("Foo.B");
```

which compiles, but fails at runtime with a cast class exception.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe way to have Map values whose generic type depends on the corresponding key.

You can, however, store the enum constants yourself:

```
private static final Map<String, Map<String, ?>> enumsMap;

static {
    enumsMap = new HashMap<>();
    // These are two DIFFERENT enum classes!
    registerEnum(SomeEnum.class);
    registerEnum(AnotherEnum.class);
}

private static <T extends Enum<T>> void registerEnum(Class<T> enumClass) {
    Map<String, ?> valuesByName =
        EnumSet.allOf(enumClass).stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Enum::name, Function.identity()));
    enumsMap.put(enumClass.getSimpleName(), valuesByName);
}

public Object[] parse(List<String> strParameters) {
    Object[] parameters = new Object[strParameters.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
        String strParameter = strParameters.get(i);
        int delim = strParameter.lastIndexOf('.');
        String className = strParameter.substring(0, delim);
        String enumName = strParameter.substring(delim + 1);
        Map<String, ?> enumValues = enumsMap.get(className);
        parameters[i] = enumValues.get(enumName);
        if (parameters[i] == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class " + className
                + " does not contain constant " + enumName);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

What I’ve changed:

- `enumsMap` is now `Map<String, Map<String, ?>>`.  Each value is a Map of enum constants keyed by constant name.  `?` is sufficient; there is no benefit to remembering that the constant values are enums, since `parse` returns `Object[]`.
- `registerEnum` has a generic type, to guarantee its argument is a valid enum type.  Instead of storing the class argument, it stores that enum’s constants.
- `parse` doesn’t need a generic type, since it returns `Object[]`.
- `parse` does not use any methods of Enum, so generic type safety is no longer a concern.
- I fixed a bug:  `strParameter.substring(0, delim);` instead of `delim - 1`.  You want the entire substring up to but not including the period.